# SUPEE-6788 APPSEC-1063 Issue

Tags: supee-6788

[SUPEE-6788 Technical details](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) says that APPSEC-1063 issues should be resolved following way:

`$collection->addFieldToFilter('(field1-field2)', array('eq'=>3));`

Should be changed to:

```
$expression = '(field1-field2)';
$condition = $this->_getConditionSql($expression, array('eq'=>3));
$this->_select->where(condition);
```

Say we have situation:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('(qty_shipped - qty_returned)', array("gt" => 0));
```

The proposed change doesn't make sense to me, since the object $collection is not involved. What is proper way to modify/fix this issue?

Comment: can you please show the full $collection code...

Comment: I found solution for this particular issue.  ->addAvailableFilter(); should be used instead this particular filter, however, question remains for custom implementations, eg. if you have  $collection->addFieldToFilter('(field1-field2)', array('eq'=>3)); in custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement needs to be implemented **within** a collection class.

The following code:

```
/** @var Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Model_Collection $collection */
$collection->addFieldToFilter('(qty_shipped - qty_returned)', array("gt" => 0));
```

Should be changed to:

*Caller*

```
/** @var Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Model_Collection $collection */
$collection->addNonReturnedFilter();
```

*Callee*

```
public function addNonReturnedFilter()
{
    /** @var Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Model_Collection $this */
    $expression = '(qty_shipped - qty_returned)';
    $condition = $this->_getConditionSql($expression, array('gt' => 0));
    $this->_select->where($condition);

    return $this;
}
```

Also have a look at the alternative approach given in the [SUPEE-6788 Technical Details](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) (using the collection's field map).

Answer (score 1):

Basically,`_getConditionSql(()`  is a **protected** function of  class `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`.

So, without  calling a `resource collection class` you could  not ***call this function***.

In a interval view,this function **is call** *Mysql PDO DB adapter*    `(Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)`  class function`prepareSqlCondition()` function  and ***that is a public function***.

For your case,you will get relative result using  **`Resource read/write adpater`** and with help of   `prepareSqlCondition()` .

---

**To read adapter:**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
```

**To write adapter:**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

**The expression may should  look this:**

```
$readAdapter- = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
    ->getConnection('core_write');

$expression = '(field1-field2)';
$inCond = $readAdapter->prepareSqlCondition($expression, $condition);

  $select = $readAdapter->select()
                ->from($Table, array('*'))
                ->where($inCond);
```

### $collection resource collection object:

If *$collection* is *`a resource collection object`* then you can use below:

> ```
> $readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
>     ->getConnection('core_write');
>
> $expression = '(field1-field2)';
> $inCond = $readAdapter->prepareSqlCondition($expression, $condition);
> $collection->getSelect()->where($inCond);
> ```